# grub crashes while opening windows7

Tags: grub2, windows-7

Previously my lap was in dual boot (W10&Ubuntu),since W10 crashes repeatedly I formatted my C partition and installed w7, and i lost grub,so I repaired grub from live USB,now the grub appears with both Ubuntu and w7 loaders but when I chose w7 it stuck on the purple window but I can hear the sound of w7 welcome tune and all,but I can't see anything it stuck in purple window (updated grub many times result is same)
Help please
Sorry for terrible English

Answer (score 0):

After a long goooogling I got a solution,simple
Install boot repair (just search on Google) on Ubuntu help page there is detailed description